# Conditionally appending to a slice of ints inside a struct without duplicates

Tags: go

I am trying to build a simple API that checks the air temperature via zipcode + an external API. It then changes a particular field in some order data I am using. Since the orders have so many fields attached, I thought it best to take the zip code along with the order key and create a smaller table that I can use to make my external weather API calls. I'm a bit of a noob so there's a good chance I am over-complicating things.

```
type Keys []int

type ZipTemp struct {
    Zip string
    Keys
    Temp string
}
```

The Temp field will be filled in after the API call.

In order to avoid paying for multiple API calls for the same zip code, I thought I would simply have a list of the Keys ([]int) for all the orders with the same zip code. That way I only have to make one API call per zip. I create the zip table by cleaning/extracting that data through a simple function, I then call the function below that organizes the data the way I would like. And it mostly works.

```
func containsKey(a, b Keys) bool {
    sort.Ints(a)
    sort.Ints(b)

    for i, v := range a {
        if v != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func SortZipTable(z []ZipTemp) {
    zipTable := z
    newZipTable := []ZipTemp{}
    lastRow := len(zipTable) - 1
    for i, v := range zipTable {
        thisRow := lastRow - i
        thisZip := v.Zip
        theseKeys := v.Keys
        ztemp := ZipTemp{}
        if thisRow <= lastRow {
            for _, vv := range zipTable {
                noDupeKeys := !containsKey(vv.Keys, theseKeys)
                if thisZip == vv.Zip {
                    if noDupeKeys {
                        theseKeys = append(theseKeys, vv.Keys...)
                    }

                    ztemp.Keys = theseKeys

                    if ztemp.Zip != thisZip {
                        ztemp.Zip = thisZip
                        newZipTable = append(newZipTable, ztemp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("newZipTable: %v \n", newZipTable)
}
```

ugly as it is, it works. However, my data still contains duplicates. The function above outputs this:

```
newZipTable: [{14127 [0] } {97754 [2] } {81623 [3] } {77657 [6] } {06385 [7] } 
{06880 [9] } {33458 [12] } {27265 [15] } {61704 [16] } {60126 [19] } {21045 [22] } 
{44106 [26] } {34243 [32] } {64118 [40] } {33027 [41] } {30152 [43] } {34609 [47] }
{37064 [51] } {28139 [52] } {76017 [53] } {30120 [59] } {22207 [62] } {29150 [65] } 
{02476 [67] } {27613 [68] } {45833 [69] } {29910 [72] } {28209 [73] } {95209 [75] }
{71112 [76] } {71957 [84] } {08857 [87] } {83646 [88] } {07825 [91] } {46324 [92] } 
{43235 [93] } {32034 [94] } {33180 [96] } {08540 [97] } {75214 [100] } {08550 [109] } 
{30135 [110] } {60622 [111] } {60610 [114] } {60622 [111 117] } {34442 [119] } 
{20001 [120] } {60134 [122] } {22306 [123] } {20007 [126] }]
```

As you can see, even though I have multiple checks, I'm still getting duplicates. Or maybe redundancy is a better word?

```
{60622 [111] } {60622 [111 117] }
```

All I want is the second one. I could write something that goes through the data yet again and removes duplicates but I'm not trying to add too much complexity as this API could potentially be dealing with 1000+ orders (initially). If I have to, I will, but something tells me I don't. Something tells me there is a much better way to do this.

I've tried at least a dozen different things, all of them only mangle the data further. At this point I'm just banging my head against the wall. I know there's a better/simpler solution to this but I'm just not quite smart enough to grasp it yet. Four days of unsuccessful googling has led me to this moment. I'll try just about anything at this point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Build map where the key is the zip and the value is a slice or orders.  Range through map getting zip and orders, get temp for zip, iterate through order with temp.  https://go.dev/play/p/1YcnzeW1Aq2

Comment: @Aaron Lain did you manage to get this working?

Comment: @Zombo -- The map idea was a solid one. I might come back to this solution if I need to optimize performance.

Comment: @CharlieClarke -- After changing the weather API to one that I actually want to use, I had to change a lot of my fundamental data structures and had to rewrite most of my code thus far, so I've implemented a much more meat-headed solution to this. Will follow up if I need to optimize.

Comment: The map is about simplicity, not performance.